# Excel column autocomplete

Tags: microsoft-excel, autocomplete

I have a question about Excel and I am not able to find a solution. It seems a basic issue but somehow it looks more complicated than I thought.

I have a column where I want the value to increase by +1 every 7 rows. I thought I could simply type the first 7 rows with 1, the next 7 rows in the same column with 2, and then select them all and double-click to extend.

But instead this is what happens:
[Sample Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmdu6.png)

Do I need a function to do this?
thanks!
M

Answer (score 1):

Let assume you are incrementing the number of column A. On A1, enter `1`. On cell A2, enter the formula:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),7)=0,A1+1,A1)
```

Drag the cell down to fill the other cells.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: first seven are supposed to be 1, not first 6. Why not just an appropriate formula in the first cell? Isn't there an absolute reference option rather than a relative one?

Comment: @fred_dot_u changed the formula based on your remark. There will be circular reference if the formula is in A1.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing won't won't like you expected. You need to use some formula for that.

There are different ways to do the same.
I have used this one:

```
=ROUNDDOWN((1+ROW()/7);0)
```

It will increase the number by 1 at every 7th row based on the row number. The result is rounded down to the whole number.

Just put this formula to the first column.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Input this formula and drag down as far as you need. Once you have what you need, replace formulas with special values (paste as text), then sort.

```
    =MOD(ROWS($A$2:A2)-1,7)+1
```

Here's the unsorted version before replacing formulas with text...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With Office 365 we can fill the column dynamically with:

```
=INT(SEQUENCE(49,,1,1/7))
```

Put that in A1 and it will spill down 49 rows with your pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see lots of answers using formulas, and copy & paste values. 
Would you like a solution that doesn't use formula(s)?

Let's say you want the 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 … sequence
in Column `A`, cells `A1:100`.

- Enter 1 in `B1` and 2 in `B8`. 
  (Leave `B2:B7` and `B9:B14` blank.)
- Select `B1:B14` and drag/fill down to `B100`. 
  This will give you 3 in `B15`, 4 in `B22`, etc.
- Select `B1:B100` and "copy" it
  (e.g., by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
- Click in `A1` and "paste"
  (e.g., by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
- Select `A2` (by clicking in it, or by pressing cursor down)
  and do "Paste" → "Paste Special" → "Add".
- Select `A3` (by clicking in it, or by pressing cursor down)
  and do "Paste" → "Paste Special" → "Add".
- Repeat the above for `A4`, `A5`, `A6` and `A7`.
- If necessary (because 100 isn't a multiple of 7) clear `A101:A105`.
- Clear Column `B`.